# codeigniter mkdir() Message: mkdir(): File exists

Tags: php, codeigniter, mkdir, file-exists

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

> Message: mkdir(): File exists
>
> Filename: controllers/Galleries.php
>
> Line Number: 88
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\panel\application\controllers\Galleries.php
>   Line: 88 Function: mkdir
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\panel\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

I changed authorization permissions to code 0777 and others, it didn't work

public function save(){

```
    $this->load->library("form_validation");

    // Kurallar yazılır...
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("title","Galeri Adı","required|trim");

    $this->form_validation->set_message(
        array(
            "required" => "<b>{field}</b> alanı doldurulmalıdır"
            )
    );


    $validate=$this->form_validation->run();



    if ($validate) {

        $gallery_type=$this->input->post("gallery_type");
        $path="uploads/$this->viewFolder/";
        $folder_name="";

        if($gallery_type=="image"){

            $folder_name=convertToSEO($this->input->post("title"));
            $path="$path/images/$folder_name";

        } else if($gallery_type=="file"){

            $folder_name=convertToSEO($this->input->post("title"));
            $path="$path/files/$folder_name";

        }

        $create_folder=mkdir($path, 0755);

        if($create_folder){

            echo "olusturuldu";

        } else{

            echo "basarisiz";

        }

        die();
```

Comment: Check if the folder/file doesn't exist before making it

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

First check if directory exists or not

```
if(!is_dir('directory-path')){
    mkdir('directory-path', 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: tried but I want to create a file with the header I entered from admin panel How can I transfer my variable that I defined as $ path to mkdir?